# I don't see any stacktrace running webapp with JBoss

Tags: jboss, richfaces, stack-trace

I have some very annoying trouble with jboss.
I'm developing simple web-app using richfaces and I'm facing the problem that when I deploy and run application in browser jboss shows just following message:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 12 at column 16: internal error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

And that's all. No stacktrace! It's so uneasy to search for a source of problem.

Could anyone help me to "turn on" stacktracing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not a logging problem. It seems like a typo. My suggestion is that remove all elements and leave page blank. Run your page and see if the page is coming. Then add components one by one. So you can inspect which element is causing the problem.